# A Twilight Zone book with a story of a couple who kill each other and travel to the future?

Tags: story-identification, the-twilight-zone

I would be grateful to any one who may have an answer. For years I have tried to find out the name of the story.

The story involves a husband and wife in the 1800’s (ish) who over time have come to hate each other. As it goes the husband goes to bar. (He leaves because he hired someone to kill his wife that night.) As he walks out of the bar he hears what he thinks in the door slamming behind him. It turns out to be a shot that "kills" him. He wakes up, his wife is there, and it's now the future. As they both killed or had killed each other their punishment was to always remain together.

That and "Back There" were in a book that my mother had, but I have been unable to find the book. Thanks again to anyone who can help me.

Comment: *Back There* only appeared in two anthologies; [Rod Serling's The Twilight Zone](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?409509) + [Chilling Stories from Rod Serling's the Twilight Zone](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?6929). I haven't got either book but 'Avenging Ghost' or 'Judgment Night' sound like likely titles...

Comment: @User14111 - Does your book contain *all* of the stories mentioned on ISFDB as potential hits from those two books?

Comment: I agree that you might be conflating two groups.  All of the TZ anthologies contained adaptions of the episodes by Serling that were part of the broadcast series.  (It's what we did before home video.)  There were a few books published years later that consisted of original stories in the same vein as the series.  These include at least three books of short stories, edited by his wife Carol.  There was also one I ran across a few years back that contained mostly forgettable ghost stories.  Try what I did, Google image search Carol Serling books and see if you recognize any covers.